# Get properties of node inside Forge Autodesk viewer

Tags: javascript, node.js, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I work with Forge Autodesk. I display a 3D building in the viewer.

I would like to know if there is a way to get a node properties (in the viewer).

I have the node number of a floor, and now I want to get the floor's position and rotation values inside the viewer. Since it is a plane surface, I suppose it must have some local coordinates saved somewhere. This [post](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2015/09/geometry-snapping-and-selection-commands-with-view-data-api.html) seems to confirm it.

Answer (score 1):

By default each nodes (components) have no rotation and a null translation applied to them. What you need is to access each vertices of a specific node in order to determine an accurate extent in 3D space. Alternatively you can also access the bounding box of a node to give you an approximation. Take a look at the following articles:

[Accessing mesh information](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2015/07/accessing-mesh-information-with-the-view-data-api.html)

[Getting bounding boxes of each component in the viewer](https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2015/08/getting-bounding-boxes-of-each-component-in-the-viewer.html)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.

The following articles helped me a lot :

[Get THREE.Mesh elements in Autodesk Forge Viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41232207/get-three-mesh-elements-in-autodesk-forge-viewer)

[How Autodesk Forge viewer manages multiple scenes to select multiple elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41248260/how-autodesk-forge-viewer-manages-multiple-scenes-to-select-multiple-elements)

[Getting bounding boxes of each component in the viewer](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2015/08/getting-bounding-boxes-of-each-component-in-the-viewer.html)

In the end, I used the fragIds to access the bounding box of a sub-element of the 3D object.